# using vue-chartjs in vue 3 : createElement is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I'm using Vue.js 3 and I can't make a chart with Vue-chartjs because of this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: createElement is not a function
    at Proxy.render (BaseCharts.js?86fc:8)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:673)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4475)
    at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
    at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4458)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4416)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4376)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3991)
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4180)
```

this is App.vue that displays my chart:

```
<template>
  <line-chart />
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from "./components/Chart";
export default {

  name: "App",
  components: {
    LineChart
  }
};
</script>
```

and this is Chart.vue that renders a line chart :

```
<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";
export default {
  extends: Line,
  data: () => ({
    chartdata: {
      labels: ["January", "February"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Data One",
          backgroundColor: "#f87979",
          data: [40, 20]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
  }
};
</script>
```

I have tried this with various forms of data, but apparently, the problem is elsewhere.
Do I have to wait for the vue.js 3 ecosystem to become more complete?

Comment: Maybe because of this https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/render-function-api.html#_2-x-syntax

Comment: thank you but I don't think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs

Vue Charts does not seem to be ready for vue3

Compatibility

```
v1 later @legacy
    Vue.js 1.x
v2 later
    Vue.js 2.x
```

Discussion about vue3 here: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/601
and here: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/637

Comment: See last comment on that issue, that might get it to work ...

Comment: See this comment. It worked for me https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/695#issuecomment-912446520

Answer (score 15):

**Update 2022**

The library supports vue 3 now and you can install as follows :

```bash
pnpm add vue-chartjs chart.js
# or
yarn add vue-chartjs chart.js
# or
npm i vue-chartjs chart.js
```

**Old answer**

According to this [issue](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/637) this library doesn't support Vue 3 yet, and the origin of this error could explained [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/render-function-api.html#render-function-argument) :

in vue 2 we do the following to create a render function :

```js
export default {
  render(createElement ) { // createElement  could be written h
    return createElement('div')
  }
}
```

in Vue 3 :

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

export default {
  render() {
    return h('div')
  }
}
```

which means that `createElement` is undefined