# Initialize a Chart.js chart with data from an api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-component, vuejs3

As I mentioned in my title I would like to initialize a Chart.js chart with an api. I found tutorials but they mostly update the data after the page is rendered. I would like to update the chart before the page is rendered. So I directly see the initialized chart without a reload.

```
<template>
    <h3>Stacked</h3>
    <Chart type="bar" v-if="isReady" :data="stackedData" :options="stackedOptions"/>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import {defineComponent, ref} from 'vue';
export default {
 
    data()  {  
 
       return {
              isReady: false,
              stackedData: {
                labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Something',
                    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
                    data: this.list_all
                }, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Another',
                    backgroundColor: '#66BB6A',
                    data: this.list_intersection
                }]
            },
           
            stackedOptions: {
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            },
            basicOptions: null,

//---------------------------------------------------
            all:[]
            list_intersection:[],
            list_all:[]
        }    
    },

    beforeCreate() {
            let apiKaderURL = 'http://localhost:4000/apiKader';
            axios.get(apiKaderURL).then(res => {

                this.all = res.data;
                this.saveData()
                this.isReady=true;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        },

     methods:{
       saveData: function (){
          
          for (var i in this.all){
                if(this.all[i].id==='2' ){
                    this.list_all.push(this.all[i].someNumber)
                }
                if(this.all[i].id==='8'){
                    this.list_intersection.push(this.all[i].someNumber) 
                }                     
           }
           return this.list_all && this.list_intersection
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am simply trying to get values with axios, filter them and then return them back to the data property of the chart objects so it gets initialized with these values.

I thought, because I call `beforeCreate`, it should work, because I initialize the values before rendering but the chart does not show any values.

I did also try to do it with `vue-chartjs` but I think it is not really working with Vue 3 or I did something wrong.

How can I accomplish that?
Thank you really much in advance.

Comment: The problem is not with (a)synchronicity if the `v-if` doesn't help.  Can you show the `<chart>` component?

Comment: I simply imported it in the main.js as mentioned here https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/chart . Do I have to define the component on my own ?

Comment: please check this GiHub issue page https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/379
chartJS is not reactive to data change

Comment: @FilipKováč Ok, thank you. I think as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114215/using-vue-chartjs-in-vue-3-createelement-is-not-a-function the libary seems to be not supporting vue 3 by now. I also tried to use it before and I have a lot of issues with it. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you were able to get the example to work from Primevue docs, there's no obvious reason your code shouldn't also work with a `v-if`, unless some data/options are poorly formatted.

Comment: The example works fine when I set the values in the return function for example ```data: ['200','300']```. I tried to do a list on my own like `this.list_all= ['20','30']` and that also didnt work but this shoud have the same format as the initial data property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle hooks (like `beforeCreate`, etc.) don't actually delay the subsequent component lifecycle steps, even when async, they just provide an entry point in which to run code.

Use a `v-if` to delay the rendering of the chart until the data is ready.  The `v-if` acts like a `watch` and won't render the chart at all until then.  Use an `isReady` variable which you will set when the data is finished saving:

```html
<Chart type="bar" v-if="isReady" :data="stackedData" :options="stackedOptions"/>
```

```js
data()  {  
  return {
    isReady: false,
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
axios.get(apiKaderURL).then(res => {
  this.all = res.data;
  this.saveData()
  this.isReady = true;  // Triggering the `v-if`
})
```

<sup>(Untested, but should work on principle)</sup>

---

Additionally, you can't set a data property from another data property using `this`, it will be `undefined`.  You can just set them to `null`:

```js
data: this.list_all  // Does nothing, can't use `this` like that
data: null           // Change to this
```

So set it to `null` and fix the `saveData` method:

```js
methods: {
  saveData() {
    const listAll = [];
    const listIntersection = [];

    for (var i in this.all){
      if(this.all[i].id==='2' ){
        listAll.push(this.all[i].someNumber)
      }
      if(this.all[i].id==='8'){
        listIntersection.push(this.all[i].someNumber) 
      }                     
    }
   
    this.stackedData.datasets[0].data = listAll;
    this.stackedData.datasets[1].data = listIntersection;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Chart.js before, but I read through Installation, Integration, and Usage documentation and came up with an example that might help you (Vue 2 with Vue CLI).

I used my App.vue SFC as the parent of the child chart component ChartTest.vue.  In the parent, I simulated an API call delay using a 'setTimeout' call in the 'mounted' hook.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <chart-test v-if="dataReady" :chartData="chartData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChartTest from '@/components/ChartTest'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      ChartTest
    },
    data() {
      return {
        chartData: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        dataReady: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getData() {
        this.dataReady = true;
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // Simulate API call
      setTimeout(this.getData(), 2000);
    }
  }
</script>
```

ChartTest.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-test">
    <h3>Chart Test</h3>
    <canvas id="my-chart" width="400" height="400" ref="chartref"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Chart from 'chart.js';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        myChart: null
      }
    },
    props: {
      chartData: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.myChart = new Chart(this.$refs.chartref, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: this.chartData,
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you put in to solve my question. I played a little bit with it and this would also solves my issue :-)